# pyqt thread seperating makes the program crash

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qthread

I'm testing some gui interactions between threads to apply it to my program, but the program just suddenly crashes if I try it.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        qv = QVBoxLayout()
        self.board = QLabel(self)
        self.board.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.board.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;")
        qv.addWidget(self.board)
        self.setLayout(qv)
        self.show()
        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.setparent.connect(self.setparent)
        self.thread.start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.thread.exit(0)

    @pyqtSlot(QWidget)
    def setparent(self, widget):
        widget.setParent(self)

class Thread(QThread):
    setparent = pyqtSignal(QWidget)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        label = QLabel()
        self.setparent.emit(label)

    def __del__(self):
        print("Thread terminated")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Window()
    app.exec_()
```

As you can see, thread emitts "setparent" signal and main thread connects it to its setparent slot.
However, it just crashes without any traceback even though I only try setting parent of widget.

Comment: Given that the accepted answer says you can't do what you've done, I would encourage you to consider asking a question where you explain what you are trying to do so that someone can give advice on how to use threads correctly for that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI should not be updated directly in another thread that is not the main thread, and this also means that you should not create the widgets in another thread

read the following: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread